# 2.92 issues with weights when generating a rig for my model

Tags: rigging

Tried  including the blend file to Blend-Exchange but too large The problem I am having is when I generate rig the weights I have assigned get messed up from the meta rig. I have tested moving the bones around when I weight painted and fixed any issues with mis-assigned weights. When I generate the rig and parent with auto weights finger pieces and parts of the shields on the forearms either dont follow or are stuck to other parts of the body. I have the meta rig parented to the body at this time is that correct to do? . Was wondering if someone could pinpoint the issue or is it an issue with the mesh Ive modeled. this my first attempt at rigging so a good chance Im lost. Help!

Comment: hello, you need to copy paste the link that Blend-Exchange has given

Comment: Srry said file too large 42,6 MB

Comment: any way to do a zip file?

Comment: choose another platform then